# Yii2 query error

Tags: php, yii2

estoy haciendo una query en Yii2 y el resultado tiene que ser: rojo, negro.

Aqui pongo lo que tengo hecho:

```
$query = $this->getSec()->select('name')->limit(2)->asArray()->all();
```

> Resultado: array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(9) "rojo" } [1]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(9) "negro" } }

```
$querySector = implode(",", $query);
```

> Resultado: Array to string conversion

Alguna idea de como hacerlo? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pretendes hacer no puedes hacerlo de esa manera ya que tu arreglo es multidimensional, con lo siguiente puedes hacerlo;

```php
    $data = [
        ["name"=>"rojo"],
        ["name"=>"negro"]
    ];

    echo implode(', ', array_column($data, 'name')); // rojo, negro
```

Con esto obtendrás el resultado de la función `implode` del `array` por un indice especifico.

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes acceder al key "name" con array column y hacer el implode. Escribe y ejecuta esto y verás:

```
echo implode(', ', array_column($query, 'name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

La query debería ser

```
$this->getSec()->select('name')->limit(2)->column();
```